# Max and Min of $|f(z)|$ on $|z-i-1| \leq 1 $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the values of $z$ in in $R$ where  $|f(z)|$ achieves its maximum and minimum values Where

$R$ is $|z-i-1|\leq1$ and $f=z$ .

I set $z-i-1 =w $ So $|w|\leq 1$ Now 
$$|z|=|z-i-1+i+1|\leq|w|+|i+1|=\sqrt2+1$$

And the minimum $| z|_{min} $ is  $\sqrt 2 -1$ How Can I find the min ?

The answer is

[image]

Thank you .

I don't know how I get that answer

Answer (score 1):

$|z-i-1|\leq 1$ is a closed circular disc with radius $1$ and center at $1+i$. The point closest and farthest on it from the origin are the points of the boundary circle which are intersected by the line joining origin and the center. So they are $|1+i|-1=\sqrt{2}-1$ and $|1+i|+1=\sqrt{2}+1$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a graphical approach may help:

You can view the area $R=|z-i-1| \leq 1$ as the circle with radius one, centered around $i+1$. The function $|f(z)|=|z|$ represents the modulus of each the numbers of $R$. So therefore, you chose the numbers closest to the origin as the minimum and the number furthest from the origin as the maximum.

You can find these numbers as lying on the line $a=b$ for the numbers $a+bi$ and satisfying that $z-i-1$=1.

This gives you the equation $|a+ai-i-1|=1 \Leftrightarrow 2(a-1)^2=1$. Solving this gives you $a=1 + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt2$ or $a=1 - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt2$. Inserting this back into $z=a+ai$ gives you your numbers.